# What is the best way to query large tables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I'm newer to SQL so this question may be simple but say I have 100,000 products and each has a brand. Say there are 400 brands.

If I want to show a brand's own products on a brand page... is it best to just query all products where brand === X or there a more performant way to do this with an index or view?

Is there a more performant way to query a brand from 100,000 rows than the basic SELECT? Or setup an index so it's faster?

```sql
SELECT brand
FROM products
WHERE brand = "ABC"
```

Any way to do dynamic Views like this?

```sql
CREATE VIEW brand_products AS SELECT
   id,
   image,
   title,
   price,
   brand,
   created_at
FROM
   products
WHERE
   brand = %ABC%
ORDER BY
   created_at DESC;
```

Comment: Yes, an index will make it faster, but you still need to "*query all products where brand === X*" - the SQL statement doesn't change.

Comment: When working on performance improvements, you always need a query plan. Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to get a plan and the results from that plan. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html

Comment: I guess I should just pagination results to improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

A view is (almost) nothing but a shorthand for the defining query, so it won't affect performance if you use one or not. The decisive factor for performance is an index on the column you search for.

Comment: I guess the answer to my own question now should be to paginate results with  SELECT query.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/pagination-problem-total-result-count/) is sn article about pagination.